# Programmatically writing stdin for an os.Process

Tags: go

Update: To programmatically "drive" `bash`, you need a Pseudo terminal (PTY).This is what I looking for:

#### https://github.com/kr/pty

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/kr/pty"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    c := exec.Command("grep", "--color=auto", "bar")
    f, err := pty.Start(c)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    go func() {
        f.Write([]byte("foo\n"))
        f.Write([]byte("bar\n"))
        f.Write([]byte("baz\n"))
        f.Write([]byte{4}) // EOT
    }()
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, f)
}
```

---

Given the following example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    attr := &os.ProcAttr{
        Files: []*os.File{os.Stdin, os.Stdout, os.Stderr},
    }
    process, err := os.StartProcess("/bin/bash", nil, attr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("process err %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    state, err := process.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("wait err %v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("'%+v'\n", state)
}
```

I can run `bash` as expected:

```
go run proc.go
bash-3.2$ echo foo
foo
bash-3.2$ exit
exit
'exit status 0'
```

However, I'd like to specify my own writable stream for `os.Stdin` and when I try passing it a file (`os.Open("/my/file")`), the process takes the file as stdin and exits at `io.EOF`. How can I create an "infinitely long" writable file?

Looking through the docs it seems I'd need to use `os.OpenFile` in some way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. However, you can create an os.Pipe() and push your file to one side. It will be inifinite as long as you do not close the pipe.

Comment: Thanks, that sort of worked. Only thing is, I'm not seeing any of the shell output (`bash-3.2$ `). Does it need to be in TTY mode or something?

Comment: If you are using a pipe, you will need to go through a pty indeed.